I am getting the following error while running my flutter project
Failed to execute org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$$Lambda/0x0000000800634480@13e56ce2.
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not add entry 'C:\Users\avans.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.build\builder\7.3.0\5cc912e81dea92f26b5cc8e4af1bc17c2337be2' to cache file-access.bin (C:\Users\avans.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin).
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:162)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafeIndexedCache.lambda$put$1(DefaultMultiProcessSafeIndexedCache.java:67)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:216)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:206)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCoordinator$UnitOfWorkFileAccess.writeFile(DefaultCacheCoordinator.java:472)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafeIndexedCache.put(DefaultMultiProcessSafeIndexedCache.java:67)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache.lambda$putLater$1(AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.ExclusiveCacheAccessingWorker$2.run(ExclusiveCacheAccessingWorker.java:185)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCoordinator.useCache(DefaultCacheCoordinator.java:248)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCoordinator.useCache(DefaultCacheCoordinator.java:229)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.ExclusiveCacheAccessingWorker.flushOperations(ExclusiveCacheAccessingWorker.java:175)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.ExclusiveCacheAccessingWorker.run(ExclusiveCacheAccessingWorker.java:145)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 255971 found in cache 'C:\Users\avans.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin'.
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.blockCorruptedException(FileBackedBlockStore.java:267)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.read(FileBackedBlockStore.java:246)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore.read(FileBackedBlockStore.java:123)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CachingBlockStore.read(CachingBlockStore.java:100)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore.read(FreeListBlockStore.java:86)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.StateCheckBlockStore.read(StateCheckBlockStore.java:67)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.load(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:182)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.access$1200(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:50)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache$IndexBlock.find(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:496)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache$IndexBlock.access$600(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:366)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:144)
... 18 more
After this the projects loads but why am i getting all this everytime?
I tried ruuning:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
but the problem is not solved

Try to Delete the Gradle cache manually
Sometimes, the issue lies in the Gradle cache itself. You can try manually deleting the cache.
On Windows, navigate to:
C:\Users\<YourUsername>\.gradle\caches

